# MC algorithm for a non-conjugate model

Tags: r, bayesian, montecarlo

The model is Poisson likelihood and Gaussian prior. I worked out the posterior for the model and I think that I have it coded correctly but I'm having a lot of trouble trying to implement the algorithm. I know that it's just a simple matter of not defining my variables properly but I'm not seeing where the problems lie. The code that I have so far is:

```
# Poisson model
#
#
# Log of the unnormalized posterior density:
log.post.dens = function( theta, n, sum.y, mu0, sig0 )
{ 
alpha = (log.dpois(x, lamda=exp(theta)))*dnorm(x, mu0, sig0)
}

#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

rw.sim = function( M, mu0, sig0, n, sum.y, sd.pd, theta.start )
{
# create theta array and initialize theta[1]
#
theta = rep( 0, M )
theta[1] = theta.start
acc.cnt = 0
for( ii in 2:M ) {
# Normal proposal distribution is centered at the current theta
#
theta.new = rnorm( 1, theta[ii-1], sd.pd )
log.alpha = log.post.dens( theta.new, n, sum.y, mu0, sig0 ) -
log.post.dens( theta[ii-1], n, sum.y, mu0, sig0 )
if( log.alpha > 0 || exp( log.alpha ) > runif( 1, 0, 1 ) )
{
theta[ii] = theta.new
acc.cnt = acc.cnt + 1
}
else
theta[ii] = theta[ii-1]
}
list( ac = acc.cnt, theta = theta )
}

#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

n = 200
mu0 = log(10)
sig0 = 3
yy = rpois( n, exp( mu0 ))
sd.pd = 1
theta.start = mu0
M = 100000
print( paste("M =", M, " mu0 =", mu0, " sig0 =", sig0, "sd.pd =", sd.pd,
"start", theta.start ))
res = rw.sim( M, mu0, sig0, length(yy), sum( yy ), sd.pd, theta.start )
theta = res$theta
acc.rate = res$ac / M
corr = cor( theta[1:(M-1)], theta[2:M])
print( paste("acceptance rate =", acc.rate ))
print( paste("correlation =", corr ))
3
m = 1
if( m )
{
theta0 = theta
thin.const = 40
theta = theta[ seq( .1*length(theta), length(theta), thin.const )]
}
par( mfrow=c(2,2))
hist( theta, prob=T, breaks=32 )
x = seq( min( theta ), max( theta ), len=200 )
lines( x, dnorm( x, mu0, sig0 ), col = 2)
plot( theta, type=’l’ )
acf( theta )
##pacf( theta )

#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

#
# Posterior predictive density for data on a grid
#
hist( yy, prob=T)
lim1 = max(yy) + 2
xx = 0:lim1
ppd = rep( 0, lim1+1 )
for( ii in 1:(lim1+1) )
{
ppd[ii] = (1/M)*sum(yy)*((log.dpois(x, lamda=exp(theta)))*dnorm(x, mu0, sig0))
}
points( xx+.5, ppd, col=2 )
lines( xx+.5, ppd, col=2 )
```

As I said it's my defining of parameters that's off but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: It's not totally clear what you're asking for. Are you getting specific errors? Where does the log.dpois function come from?

Comment: Sorry I should have made that much clearer. After taking a break of a few hours from it some mistakes are coming to light ie, it shouldn't be log dpopis it should be the likelihood of the poisson distribution. The errors that I'm getting are that the program doesn't recognize the theta variable. The code works until the res = rw.sim argument

Comment: The main issue I have after sorting out the log dpois mistake is            Error in if (log.alpha > 0 || exp(log.alpha) > runif(1, 0, 1)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: A couple of issues: x is not defined in the call to dpois, and lambda is misspelled as lamda, which is throwing an error. The error you are getting is indicative of another error - log.alpha is missing - probably because of the issue with "x" that I mentioned. I would  recommend learning the use of "..." in functions to deal with all of the different ways in which you use "theta". If you supply some cleaned up code, I can help, but I'm at the end of what I can do with the little information you've given.

Comment: I'm getting much closer (I think) The code that I have now is :        # Log of the unnormalized posterior density:
> log.post.dens = function( theta, n, sum.y, mu0, sig0 )
+ { 
+     log.post.dens = log(((exp(theta)^sum.y)*exp(-n*exp(theta)))*dnorm(x, mu0, sig0))
+ }   The issue that I have now is : res = rw.sim( M, mu0, sig0, length(yy), sum( yy ), sd.pd, theta.start )
Error in if (log.alpha > 0 || exp(log.alpha) > runif(1, 0, 1)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: Yes, my last comment addresses that issue.